# Merging Branches from Git

Tags: git, version-control, jira

Our development environment consists of `dev`, `demo`, and `master` branches. We use JIRA to track issues, and everytime we start an issue, we branch off of `dev`, make necessary changes, and finally push out the branch.

For testing, we first merge the branch (which corresponds to the name of a JIRA issue) into `dev`, test it, then merge into `demo`, test it, then merge into `master`.

The problem we are having is that the issues seem to be building on each other. I can best explain this with an example:

Let's say we have our typical environment, `dev`, `demo`, and `master`. There are three issues, `TEST-1`, `TEST-2`, and `TEST-3`. The issues are completed in the order in which they were created, by branching off of `dev`, working on the branch, then committing and pushing the branch. I then merge the branch into `dev`, before branching out again for the next issue.

When it comes time to push these three branches out to live, we are having unexpected results. In order to merge these into `master`, I log onto the server's command line and first run the command:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will allow me to see the new branches. Let's say we only want to push the changes for `TEST-3`. We run the command:

```
git merge origin/TEST-3
```

Rather than seeing the changes from only the third branch getting merged in, all of the changes seem to be getting pulled. So then later, when we finally do merge in the first and second issues, it gives us the message "Already up to date".

This is not what we want, as with this behavior, we are unable to back out individual branches.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can we do this in such a way that allows us to create branches for each of our issues, and merge them in one at a time, with the possibility of pulling these changes out if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described it, your workflow should work as you want it to. The only refinement I might advise is using `git merge --no-ff origin/TEST-3` to merge in work from a particular branch, so git always creates a merge commit on `dev` that you can revert later if needed, even if the merge is trivial.

Are you certain that the branches `TEST-1`, `TEST-2`, and `TEST-3` were created off of `dev` correctly? If the developer working on `TEST-2` created a new branch based on `TEST-1` by mistake, for example, then merging in `TEST-2` would also merge all of the commits on `TEST-1` that were made before the branch point. `git checkout -b TEST-2` will create a branch called TEST-2 *starting at the currently checked-out branch*, so it would be easy to accidentally branch off of the last ticket you were working on by mistake. Specifying an explicit starting point with something like `git checkout -b TEST-3 origin/dev` may cause fewer issues.

Meanwhile, you can diagnose the history you've already created with `git log` like so:

```
# Show an ASCII art graph of all branch heads. Depending on the complexity
# of your repository, this may or may not be too noisy to be useful.
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all

# Graphing specific branches might be more readable:
git log --oneline --decorate --graph dev origin/TEST-3

# Show the commits that are reachable by TEST-3, but not by dev.
# This tells you exactly what work you're about to merge in 
# If TEST-3 includes TEST-2 or TEST-1 by mistake, you'll see extra commits here.
git log --oneline origin/TEST-3 ^dev
# Or equivalently:
git log --oneline dev..origin/TEST-3
```

If you already have work on a branch that was based on the wrong starting point, you can move the commits you want back to `dev` with [`git rebase --onto`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#More-Interesting-Rebases):

```
# I like to include the -i to see what commits I'm about to move before
# the rebase actually happens.
git rebase -i --onto dev TEST-3 TEST-2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. That was extremely helpful! Perhaps my problem is that I am branching off of `dev` to create `TEST-1`, then merging `TEST-1` back into `dev` before branching for `TEST-2`. I'm thinking that `TEST-2` would essentially be, as you said, based off of `TEST-1`, indirectly.